# Как запросить ботом контактные данные пользователя Viber (номер телефона) имея его user ID.

Tags: php, python, viber

Как запросить ботом контактные данные пользователя Viber (номер телефона) имея его user ID, но чтобы пользователь его вручную не вводил. Как вариант - кнопка "Отправить контактные данные". Желательно фрагмент кода функции на python или php

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю это следующим образом, используя SDK для PHP.
Безусловно, все что описано ниже, является сугубо примером и основной акцент сделан на функционал запроса номера телефона.

```
$botSender = new Sender( [
            'name'   => 'Любое наименование бота',
            'avatar' => 'https://developers.viber.com/img/favicon.ico',
        ] );

$bot = new Bot( [ 'token' => 'Ваш API_KEY' ] );
$bot
   ->onText( '|/start|si', function ( $event ) use ( $bot, $botSender ) {

                    $bot->getClient()->sendMessage(
                        (new \Viber\Api\Message\Text())
                            ->setSender($botSender)
                            ->setReceiver($event->getSender()->getId())
                            ->setMinApiVersion(3)
                            ->setText("Нам необходим Ваш номер телефона.")
                            ->setKeyboard(
                                (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard())
                                    ->setButtons([
                                        (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard\Button())
                                            ->setActionType('share-phone')
                                            ->setActionBody('reply')
                                            ->setText('Отправить номер телефона')
                                    ])
                            )
                    );
                } )
                ->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так =) Тебе нужно просто правильно подсунуть норм конфиги а так смотри доку REST API VIBER

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers\web\admin;

use app\controllers\web\AdminController;

class ViberController extends AdminController
{

    /**
     *  Конфиги
     *  @auth_token,
     *  @send_name имя бота
     *  @is_log записавать логи или нет
     *  @webhook url
     * */
    private $auth_token = "code bot";
    private $send_name = "name bot";
    private $is_log = true;
    private $webhook = 'URL';


    // Записать что получили метод
    private function putLogIn( $data ) {
        $is_log = $this->is_log;
        if($is_log) {file_put_contents("tmp_in.txt", $data."\n", FILE_APPEND);}
    }

    // Что отправили метод
    private function putLogOut ( $data ) {
        $is_log = $this->is_log;
        if($is_log) {file_put_contents("tmp_out.txt", $data."\n", FILE_APPEND);}
    }

    /**
     * @data готовый данные который будем скидавать на вайбер вебхук
     * Метод нужен для отправки
     * */
    private function sendReq( $data ) {
        $request_data = json_encode($data);
        $this->putLogOut($request_data);

        $ch = curl_init("https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/send_message");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($err) {return $err;}
        else {return $response;}
    }

    // Готовим message
    private function sendMsg($sender_id, $text, $type, $tracking_data = Null, $arr_asoc = Null) {
        $auth_token = $this->auth_token;
        $send_name = $this->send_name;

        $data['auth_token'] = $auth_token;
        $data['receiver'] = $sender_id;
        $data['type'] = 'text';
        $data['text'] = $text;
        $data['min_api_version'] = 3;
        $data['keyboard'] = [
            "DefaultHeight" => true,
            "BgColor" => "#FFFFFF",
            'CustomDefaultHeight' => 50,
            "Buttons" => [
                [
                    "ActionType" => "share-phone",
                    "ActionBody" => "reply",
                    "Text" => "<b>Записать номер телефона</b>",
                    "Columns" => 3,
                    "Rows" => 2,
                    "BgColor" => "#00FF00",
                ],
                [
                    "Columns" => 3,
                    "Rows" => 2,
                    "BgColor" => "#2db9b9",
                    "BgMediaType" => "gif",
                    "BgMedia" => "http://www.url.by/test.gif",
                    "BgLoop" => true,
                    "ActionType" => "open-url",
                    "ActionBody" => "www.tut.by",
                    "Image" => "www.tut.by/img.jpg",
                    "Text" => "<b>Перевести на менеджера</b>",
                    "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                    "TextHAlign" => "center",
                    "TextOpacity" => 60,
                    "TextSize" => "regular",
                ],
                [
                    "Columns" => 3,
                    "Rows" => 2,
                    "BgColor" => "#00FFFF",
                    "BgMediaType" => "gif",
                    "BgMedia" => "http://www.url.by/test.gif",
                    "BgLoop" => true,
                    "ActionType" => "open-url",
                    "ActionBody" => "www.tut.by",
                    "Image" => "www.tut.by/img.jpg",
                    "Text" => "<b>Инструкция как пользоваться ботом</b>",
                    "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                    "TextHAlign" => "center",
                    "TextOpacity" => 60,
                    "TextSize" => "regular",
                ],
                [
                    "Columns" => 3,
                    "Rows" => 2,
                    "BgColor" => "#FF00FF",
                    "BgMediaType" => "gif",
                    "BgMedia" => "http://www.url.by/test.gif",
                    "BgLoop" => true,
                    "ActionType" => "open-url",
                    "ActionBody" => "www.tut.by",
                    "Image" => "www.tut.by/img.jpg",
                    "Text" => "<b>Показать товары со скидкой</b>",
                    "TextVAlign" => "middle",
                    "TextHAlign" => "center",
                    "TextOpacity" => 60,
                    "TextSize" => "regular",
                ]
            ]
        ];

        if($tracking_data != Null) {$data['tracking_data'] = $tracking_data;}
        if($arr_asoc != Null)
        {
            foreach($arr_asoc as $key => $val) {$data[$key] = $val;}
        }

        return $this->sendReq($data);
    }

    private function sendMsgText($sender_id, $text, $tracking_data = Null) {
        return $this->sendMsg($sender_id, $text, "text", $tracking_data);
    }

    // Слушаем что получили от Viber ( Если нужно будет добавить какие-то дейсвие тут нужно просто ловить запрос и обработать )
    public function actionListenRequest()
    {
        $request = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $input = json_decode($request, true);

        $this->putLogIn($request);
        $sender_id = $input['sender']['id'] ?? null; //unique viber id of user who sent the message
        $sender_name = $input['sender']['name'] ?? null; //name of the user who sent the message

        if($input['event'] == 'webhook')
        {
            $webhook_response['status'] = 0;
            $webhook_response['status_message'] = "ok";
            $webhook_response['event_types'] = 'delivered';
            echo json_encode($webhook_response);
            die;
        }
        else if($input['event'] == "subscribed")
        {
            $this->sendMsgText($sender_id, "Спасибо, что подписались на нас!");
        }
        else if($input['event'] == "conversation_started")
        {
            $this->sendMsgText($sender_id, "Беседа началась!");
        }
        elseif($input['event'] == "message")
        {
            $type = $input['message']['type']; //type of message received (text/picture)
            $text = $input['message']['text']; //actual message the user has sent
            $result = json_decode($request);
            if (!empty($result->message->contact)) {
                $phone = '+' . $result->message->contact->phone_number;
            } else {
                $phone = 'text';
            }
            $amo = \Yii::$app->amocrm->getClient();

            // Работаем API AMOCRM
            // Получение экземпляра модели для работы с контактами
            $listLead = $amo->lead->apiList([
                'query' => $phone,
            ]);
            /* кол-во записей */
            $countList = count( $listLead );
            /* Проверяем какая последняя */
            $lastLead = $listLead[ (--$countList) ];
            /* Проверка даты */
            if(!date('d', $lastLead['date_create']) === date('d')) {
                $lead = $amo->lead;
                $lead['name'] = 'Сделка Viber ' . $phone . ' тест';
                $lead['responsible_user_id'] = 1310037;
                $id = $lead->apiAdd();
            }

            /* Отправка на Viber */
            $response = $this->sendMsg($sender_id, $phone, $type);
            }

            /* Запись на проверку статуса true || false */
            file_put_contents('viber_response.txt', json_encode($response));
//        }
    }

    // Записать вебхук ( Если нужно будет поменять адрес просто поменяйте параметр URL в контролере )
    public function actionSetWebhook() {
        $jsonData =
            '{
                "auth_token": "'.$this->auth_token.'",
                "url": "'.$this->webhook.'",
                "event_types": ["subscribed", "unsubscribed", "delivered", "message", "seen"]
            }';

        $ch = curl_init('https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook');

        echo '<pre>';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));;

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $err = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($err) {echo($err);}
        else {echo($response);}
    }
}
```